# Interface TkInter aparecendo separada

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

A interface funciona, mas aparece dividida; parte do código numa janela e parte em outra.
O código foi originalmente gerado com o PAGE, mas daí eu alterei pra tanto me livrar do arquivo de suporte quanto deixar em OO, mas como não entendo muito de tk, acabei me perdendo.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class menuPrincipal:
    def __init__(self):
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])    

        self.Canvas1 = tk.Canvas()
        self.Canvas1.place(relx=0.018, rely=0.023, relheight=0.95
                , relwidth=0.964)
        self.Canvas1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Canvas1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.Canvas1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Canvas1.configure(relief="ridge")
        self.Canvas1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Canvas1.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.EntradaInput = ttk.Entry(self.Canvas1)
        self.EntradaInput.place(relx=0.047, rely=0.323, relheight=0.085
                , relwidth=0.904)
        self.EntradaInput.configure(takefocus="")
        self.EntradaInput.configure(cursor="ibeam")

        self.Confirmar = ttk.Button(self.Canvas1,command=lambda:self.pegar(self.EntradaInput))
        self.Confirmar.place(relx=0.281, rely=0.605, height=25, width=76)
        self.Confirmar.configure(takefocus="")
        self.Confirmar.configure(text='''Confirmar''')

        self.Encerrar = ttk.Button(self.Canvas1,command=lambda:sys.exit(1))
        self.Encerrar.place(relx=0.539, rely=0.605, height=25, width=76)
        self.Encerrar.configure(takefocus="")
        self.Encerrar.configure(text='''Encerrar''')

        self.Numeros = ttk.Label(self.Canvas1)
        self.Numeros.place(relx=0.351, rely=0.202, height=19, width=126)
        self.Numeros.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Numeros.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Numeros.configure(font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.Numeros.configure(relief="flat")
        self.Numeros.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Numeros.configure(justify='left')
        self.Numeros.configure(text='''Insira seus números:''')

    def iniciar(self):
        global root
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("443x261+360+115")
        root.minsize(120, 1)
        root.maxsize(1370, 749)
        root.resizable(1, 1)
        root.title("Menu principal")
        root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        root.mainloop()

    def encerrar(self):
        root.quit()

    def pegar(self, entry):
        self.numInput = entry.get()
        self.encerrar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, enfim! Foi na tentativa-e-erro, mas para caso alguém venha a encontrar isso no futuro:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class menuPrincipal:
    def __init__(self):
        global root
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("443x261+360+115")
        root.minsize(120, 1)
        root.maxsize(1370, 749)
        root.resizable(1, 1)
        root.title("Menu principal")
        root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])    

        self.Canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.Canvas1.place(relx=0.018, rely=0.023, relheight=0.95
                , relwidth=0.964)
        self.Canvas1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Canvas1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.Canvas1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Canvas1.configure(relief="ridge")
        self.Canvas1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Canvas1.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.EntradaInput = ttk.Entry(self.Canvas1)
        self.EntradaInput.place(relx=0.047, rely=0.323, relheight=0.085
                , relwidth=0.904)
        self.EntradaInput.configure(takefocus="")
        self.EntradaInput.configure(cursor="ibeam")

        self.Confirmar = ttk.Button(self.Canvas1,command=lambda:self.pegar(self.EntradaInput))
        self.Confirmar.place(relx=0.281, rely=0.605, height=25, width=76)
        self.Confirmar.configure(takefocus="")
        self.Confirmar.configure(text='''Confirmar''')

        self.Encerrar = ttk.Button(self.Canvas1,command=lambda:sys.exit(1))
        self.Encerrar.place(relx=0.539, rely=0.605, height=25, width=76)
        self.Encerrar.configure(takefocus="")
        self.Encerrar.configure(text='''Encerrar''')

        self.Numeros = ttk.Label(self.Canvas1)
        self.Numeros.place(relx=0.351, rely=0.202, height=19, width=126)
        self.Numeros.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Numeros.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Numeros.configure(font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.Numeros.configure(relief="flat")
        self.Numeros.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Numeros.configure(justify='left')
        self.Numeros.configure(text='''Insira seus números:''')

    def iniciar(self):
        root.mainloop()

    def encerrar(self):
        root.quit()

    def pegar(self, entry):
        self.numInput = entry.get()
        self.encerrar()
```